# Oepncart shopping cart for B2B site

Tags: shopping-cart, opencart

I'm very new to shopingcarts and am very impressed with Opencart. After looking under the hood, is there a way to allow users who register to add their own products to be sold? In effect, it becomes a B2B site like alibaba.com or ebay.

Feel free to correct me if I'm not approaching this the right way. I'm also open to other suggestions on which cart I should be using...as long as it's not Magento. hehe

Answer (score 0):

That would require extensive modding, you definitely won't find this solution for free. I personally don't think this platform is well-suited for this, but of course it could be done, it's a straightforward MVC platform.